# How to correct distortion from stitching dual camera to estimate homography

Tags: computer-vision

I am trying to distort the image obtained from two cameras that generate a stitching image. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the cameras and I would like to know what could be the best way to apply to correct the image and get the lines below to be straight.

[image]

The next step I am trying to do is to calculate the homography with respect to the field. And the only thing that I find is that: transformation between the image field and the template field plane has to be done through a linear transformation.